# Show sub list after click on list item

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I have the following json being delivered to my view:

```
$scope.mockData = [
  {
    "folder": "folder1",
    "reports": [{ "name": "report1" }, { "name": "report2" }, { "name": "report3" }]
  },
  {
    "folder": "folder2",
    "reports": [{ "name": "report5" }, { "name": "report6" }, { "name": "report7" }]
  },
  {
    "folder": "folder3",
    "reports": [{ "name": "report8" }, { "name": "report9" }, { "name": "report10" }]
  }
];
```

To iterate over the folder list I have this in my view:

```
<div class="row" ng-repeat="item in mockData | filter:query">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <a href="" class="list-group-item" ng-cloak >
      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-close"></i>
      &nbsp;{{item.folder}}
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to implement the following functionality into my view:
When I click on the:

```
<a href="" class="list-group-item" ng-cloak >
      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-close"></i>
      &nbsp;{{item.folder}}
</a>
```

I should be shown a new div but now with the items in:

```
"reports": [{ "name": "report1" }, { "name": "report2" }, { "name": "report3" }
```

How would I do this ?

Comment: Question is very vague. Please review [ask] and edit question with proper description of exactly what you are trying to do.... *"display names"* isn't very meaningful without context

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a boolean parameter to your MOCK JSON, such as 'showFolderContents':false.   Add an ng-click behavior to your folder icon, and when it's clicked have it toggle that parameter between true/false.  Then within your ng-repeat='item in mockData', you'll have to created a nested ng-repeat='report in item.reports' with an ng-show='item.showFolderContents'.

You can handle the ng-click behavior with something like this:

```
<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-close" ng-click='toggleShowingFolderContents(item)></i>
```

and in your angular make a function such as:

```
$scope.toggleShowingFolderContents = function(item){
item.showFolderContents = !item.showFolderContents
}
```

So your html would wind up looking like so :

```
<div class="row" ng-repeat="item in mockData | filter:query">
<div class="col-md-6">
<a href="" class="list-group-item" ng-cloak >
  <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-close" ng-  click='toggleShowingFolderContents(item)></i>
<div ng-show='item.showFolderContents'>
<div ng-repeat='report in item.reports'>
{{report.name}}
</div>
</div>
```